# jenkins complicated buildflow, is it possible?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-agent

[image]

I would like to have a Jenkins build flow that looks like this.

- After the build is triggered all slaves run the same job in parallel (a setup job).
- If any slaves fail this job they should not continue on.
- For the all the slaves that to pass that job, they should grab a job out of a pool of jobs that need to be completed. And once a slave completes a job they should go back to complete another job in the pool.

I have only started working with Jenkins a few weeks ago and they way I have it setup now is as each job is picked up by a slave they have to run the setup job first. This really slows down build times because I have about 30 jobs and the setup takes ~2 minutes.

I am using Jenkins as an automated testing platform and all the jobs in the job pool can run independently of each other. I have 5 slaves currently and ~30 jobs.

Comment: Jenkins already has a job pool. Having multiple pools ( labeled workers ) is common but having dynamically relabeled is not done. Can we talk more about your setup? Why can't we do this before hand on your workers (before they've joined the jenkins worker pool). What _type_ of workers are you using ( in a world where they can be VMs, ec2 instances, docker containers...) ?

Comment: The workers are all seperate physical machines. The main reason for the setup step is to start the program I intend to test. I like keeping that separate from the rest of the tests because it often doesn't start and I want that failure to be represented as a start up failure and not a feature failure. We have lots of failures and if I have to dig into how each test failed what is the point of having automated testing. I am not against another approach I just want to attempt to only have the start the program once per slave per build and in each build my slaves will pickup 5-7 testing jobs.

Comment: That isn't hard, especially if you put it in "stages" in a pipeline. Pipeline also separates the logs for easier viewing, check it out. I'll start answer below

Answer (score 0):

The following should do the trick:

```
def jobPool = new ArrayDeque()
jobPool.add({
    echo "Doing stuff on ${env.NODE_NAME}"
});
jobPool.add({
    echo "Doing other stuff on ${env.NODE_NAME}, a little slower"
    sleep 4
});
jobPool.add({
    echo "Doing more stuff on ${env.NODE_NAME}, even slower"
    sleep 10
});
jobPool.add({
    echo "Doing stuff quick on ${env.NODE_NAME}"
});
jobPool.add({
    echo "Doing stuff quicker on ${env.NODE_NAME}"
});


def par = [:]

for (x in ["master", "urban"]) {
    def nodeName = x; // needed due to variable scoping
    par[nodeName] = {
        node (nodeName) {
            try {
               echo "Doing setup on ${env.NODE_NAME}!"
               // Do you're setup
               echo "Done with setup"
            } catch (Exception e) {
               echo "Will not use this node as it failed setup!"
               return;
            }
            while (true) {
               // echo "${jobPool.size()}"
                def subTask = jobPool.poll()
                //echo "${jobPool.size()} ${subTask}"
                if (subTask == null) {
                    break;
                }
                // Might wan't try catch around the next line if you wan't to continue if a job fails
                subTask()
            }
        }
    }
}
parallel par
if (!jobPool.isEmpty()) {
  error "Not all tasks was done!"
}
```

Simply add your "job pool jobs" to the `jobPool` variable and modify the setup part.

Comment: Sorry if this is a nooby question, but where would I put a script like this? I have always just created jobs in jenkins UI and used the Execute shell build option.

Comment: Aha, sorry, create a job of the type Pipeline Job, not Freestyle job

Comment: This is very close to what I want. However, it seems when I go to build a job like this: build 'testing_helloworld' jenkins picks a random node instead of the node who issued the build command.

Comment: Jenkins can't do that by default, you probably want to use the NodeLabel plugin

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want separate stages in the same job. This is made much easier in jenkins 2's pipelines. There are some pictures here:
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Stage+View+Plugin

the [groovy] code ends up looking like this:

```
node {
  stage 'Checkout'
  svn 'https://svn.mycorp/trunk/'
  stage 'Build'
  sh 'make all'
  stage 'Test'
  sh 'make test'
}
```